# Create a permanent window in place but changes have increased

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to get directions please.
I want to build a Web page with jQuery and split it to several windows,
So that each window can change the increased considerably change its boundaries.

the vertical partition window I can move it up or down.
the horizontal partition window I can move it left or right.

As the following picture has red window is fixed location but you can enlarge the window up or lower down the window.[examle window](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/demo.PNG)

Thanks.

Comment: I was going to edit your post but I figured you should revise it yourself. It really could be better. For what it's worth, *Windows* are not *Panels*. Windows usually can be moved around, like dialogs. Container widgets are known as *panes* or *panels*. The widget between panes that allows resizing is called a *splitter*.

Answer (score 0):

[Frames](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp) is the thing you're looking for!

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use frames for this. I don't see any good that frames will bring you here

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery UI resizable component:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I think you need a splitter UI layout, such as [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm).